# What is sprayed at a rocket launch? And why?

Tags: launch, launchpad

Looking at [recent SpaceX launches](http://youtu.be/lbHnSu-DLR4?t=15m3s) there is some, probably water, sprayed to the flames. Why?

Answer (score 3):

According to NASA, they spray water for two purposes:

> Thousands of gallons of water flood the launch area at the crucial moments surrounding ignition, serving two purposes. Water keeps flames from spreading and prevents damage caused by sound waves.

Source: http://www.nasa.gov/audience/forstudents/9-12/features/F_Preventing_Fires_on_the_Launchpad_prt.htm